# Session destroy not working in session handler class

Tags: php, session

I use [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7357-PHP-Store-session-data-in-MySQL-using-PDO.html) but have issue. All sessions found in the database are not deleted.

What command to clear the session from the database should be used?

I tested with Firefox and Chrome. This is my code for clear session:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once '../inc/class_session.inc.php';
$session = new Session();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']) OR !isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    unset($_SESSION['admin']);
    unset($_SESSION['userid']);
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: avaliale in class link.

Comment: I'm not going to download that class

Comment: dont need to download class you can view code with click here http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/38657.html